# .net No strings comparison methods are working

Tags: c#, .net, string, comparison

Well, I've been trying to build a simple login (Nothing that complicated), everything is working correctly, but not the part when u need to compare the database results and the user input.
Here's the problem:

```
if (item.user == User && item.password == Password) {
  itExists = true;
  break;
}
```

item.usuario is working correctly, the user input is saving correctly too, I know this, because when I try to compare with this:

```
if (item.user.Contains(User) && item.password.Contains(Password)) {
  itExists= true;
  break;
}
```

It works "fine", the problem with "Contains" is that when the user type a single letter (For example, imagine if in database, the user/password is admin/admin and the user types a/a) it will let him sign in, because "a" is contained in "admin"

So, I've searched almost all the comparison methods and I've tried this:

```
// Isn't working directly. ToString(item.user) == Convert.ToString(User) && Convert.ToString(item.password) == Convert.ToString(Password)
                // Isn't working directly. item.user== User && item.password == Password
                // Isn't working directly. item.user.Equals(User) && item.password.Equals(Password)
                // Isn't working directly. String.Equals(item.user, User) && String.Equals(item.password, Password)
                // Is working, but if u write a single letter that is in the string,
                // It let u sign in. item.user.Contains(User) && item.password.Contains(Password)
```

I know those don't work because with .Contains() it let u sign in with a correct user/password, but with the issue I've told

I want to know why this happens, and, how to do it then.

Each variable contains:

- item.user is an iteration of a foreach (That is bringing the database users information)
- User is the input of the user (html form)

The complete controller code is here:

```
public ActionResult Index(string User, string Password) {
        var UsersList= db.Users;
        bool itExists= false;
        foreach (var item in UserList) {
            if (item.user.Contains(User) && item.password.Contains(Password)) {
               itExists= true;
               break;
}}
```

(I think I've explained myself really fine, sorry if I didn't)

Thank u in advance :)

Edit: If it matters, I'm using ASP.NET (.Net Framework 4.7.2)

Comment: Can you share the value of each variable in the if ?

Comment: I'll edit the question to add this, on my way to do this, thank u!

Comment: Quick bit of advice, don't store plain text passwords ever, ever.

Comment: password.Contains(Password) means is the word represented by Password contained in the word represented by password. It doesn't mean is Password contained in the database

Comment: First, are you 100% sure the strings are equal? Sometimes there'd be non-printable characters in there. It's happened to me.

Comment: @insane_developer Im 100% the string are equal (I've tried it typing it myself and copy/paste from database)

Comment: @Codexer I know I can't store passwords as plain text, I'm just practicing, this is not going to go to production site, but thank you for the advice

Comment: @Shanie item.password is the password of the foreach iteration, so it is the database data and I'm comparing that to the user input

Comment: @SebastiánVillegas can you share an example of two strings that are supposedly equal but are not in code? There is something you are not seeing, for sure.

Comment: @SebastiánVillegas Rather than practicing using techniques you know you shouldn't and building bad habits, practice using the techniques you know you *should* be using so you build good habits.

Comment: @SebastiánVillegas I understand that you're getting  password from the db, but the question you're asking is wrong. password must EQUAL Password.

Comment: @SebastiánVillegas what are you meant to be returning from the Index method?

Comment: @Shanie Yes, but the problem is there, the .Equals or "==" is simply not working in the foreach

Comment: @Servy You're right, I'm going to start applying it more. Thanks

Comment: @insane_developer There's a single user in the database user: admin password: admin those are the strings I have to compare with the user input

Comment: @SebastiánVillegas so you are claiming that "admin" is not equal to "admin" in code, but reading other comments of yours, it appears that your issue was trimming, or lack thereof. So, that answers your original post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the password you should stick to an "==" comparaison. The password sent by the user should match exactly what is in database (by the way you should use an hash and not the actual password but it's not the issue here).

For the username you can be more flexible (by example the user will maybe use capital letter or adding a blank space behind) so you should take care of that :

```
item.usuario.Trim().Equals(User, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);
```

With the Trim() you will remove all whitespace before/after and the Equals parameter will ensure the comparison will be case insensitive.

You should also trim the "User" if if what not done before adding it to the database.

You also should use LINQ instead of a for each :

```
var trimmedUserName = item.usuario.Trim();
var exists = UserList.Any(u => trimmedUserName.Equals(User, 
StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) && item.password == Password);
```

And I'm sure you know it but using the ".Contains" would be a huge security issue.

Comment: Why should we use LINQ instead of foreach? I think "should" is not conveying the right message here.

Comment: Maybe not the right word. It just LINQ is usually (when correctly written) more readable and it's adviced by some code analyzer or refactoring tool :-)

Comment: Ok, I tried the user code you posted and the comparison with the password using "==" but it didn't work.

So, using the LINQ it would be like this? 

`foreach (var item in UserList) {
                    var trimmedUserName = item.user.Trim();
                    encontrado = UserList.Any(u => trimmedUserName.Equals(User, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) && item.password == Password);
                } `

^ This is working perfectly, but I don't get how to get rid of the foreach there

Comment: I disagree about the more readable part. Correct and readable can very well be inversely related when it comes to LINQ.

Comment: @SebastiánVillegas Using the linq you should remove the foreach. The "UserList.Any" will go through all the list for you. If if not working can you copy paste here the two password (from database and from the user ?)

Comment: @insane_developer Well at least LINQ operation convey an intent. With a loop you cannot say as quickly what is the purpose of it and usually for simple operation it will ask you more lines of code. In this case an "Any" indicate me he just want to know if there is a least one element corresponding to his search. With a loop I have to read until the "break" to understand one is enough. It's a personal opinion of course but often I found LINQ more readable when correctly written :-)

Comment: Ok, my bad, I didn't see the "u" in the .Any, so this is the code that solved everything
`                itExists = UserList.Any(u => u.user.Trim().Equals(User, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) && u.password == Password);
 `

Answer (score 0):

I think you should rearrange your Index method.

```
  public ActionResult Index(string User, string Password) {
     var dbUser = _db.Users
        .FirstOrDefault(u => u.UserName == User && u.password == Password);

     if(dbUser != null)
        itExists = true;
     
     return Ok(itExists);
  }}
```

Comment: Since you don't really want to user the dbUser but just to know if it exists I think the ".Any" operator is more appropriate.

Comment: @Arcord  You're probably right, I'd just assumed that he was going to do something else with the user.